# How to get If statement to return DataFrame instead of Any in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, if-statement, expression

I'm trying to use if-else statement as expressions, but what I'm getting is a return type of `Any` instead of the desired `DataFrame`.

Here's a reproducible

```
val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (0, "a"),
      (1, "b"),
      (2, "c"),
      (3, "a"),
      (4, "a"),
      (5, "c")
    )).toDF("id", "category")

val x  = if (true){
  val y = 1
  val x1 = df1.withColumn("id2", $"id"+y)
  x1
} 
//x: Any = [id: int, category: string ... 1 more field]
```

Why is `x` of type `Any` instead of `DataFrame`?

Comment: because you're missing `else`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's essentially because the compiler doesn't know whether the argument of your if statement is `true` or `false`. Since it doesn't know it will just default to inferring the return type as `Any`. (I think what actually happens is the return type will be the "smallest" common supertype of all branches of your if-else expression and since if there's no final else the default value is just `Unit`; e.g. try `println(if (false) "Hello!")` hence the smallest common supertype in this case is in fact `Any`)

If you want to force your value to always have a type of `Dataset` you can use an else like this:

```
val x: DataFrame = if (true) {
        val y  = 1
        val x1 = df1.withColumn("id2", $"id" + y)
        x1
      } else spark.emptyDataFrame
```

PS:

Just to illustrate the point about the compiler inferring the smallest common supertype here's a concrete example:

```
val myBool: Boolean = ???

val x: TraversableOnce[Int] = if(myBool) Iterator.single(1) else List(1)
```

The compiler will infer that `x` has a type of `TraversableOnce[Int]` because this is the smallest common supertype of `List[Int]` and `Iterator[Int]`

Comment: To draw out this point more: when an if-else clause has no final else block, it is possible none of the if/else if clauses evaluate, the implicit Any type is inferred, so a final else clause is needed with an object that is of the needed type